# LibreOffice Calc (date has past coditional formatting)

Tags: conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I am building a to do list in LibreOffice. I have one column that describes the task and next to it is the deadline date. I would like any task that is past it's deadline to be a different color. Is it possible to do this using conditional formatting?

Just to clarify. I just managed to work something out by using "if cell value is less than TODAY()" however this only changes the look of the date cell. I also need to change the two cells in front of the date.

Thanks in advance[Image of to do list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSkla.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. Just selected the entire list and used conditional formatting 'formula is $C2 < TODAY()'. This seems to work fine.